# Using json objects (with maintained schema in registry) vs. string vs. hash as message key

Tags: apache-kafka

Folks,

I am wondering if there is any dis/advantage to using json objects as message keys.

Assume I have 2 event streams coupled with 2 tables in a source system. Each of those tables have its own business keys;

1. Product table has `product_number` and `base_product_id` as business key in the source system (key: `product_number`, `base_product_id`)
2. Invoice table has `invoice_id` as its business key and `prod_id` and `prod_num` as foreign key that point to Product table in the source system.

I’d like to enrich my Invoice stream with records in a globalKtable built on top of my Product event stream in a kstream application by applying an inner join between the two.

I can think of 3 ways to configure my data producers for assigning keys:

1. concatenate the value of the keys. e.g.: key=valueOf(prod_id).concat(prod_num)
2. define key as json object with schema maintained in schema registry. e.g.: key={“prod_id”: “AAM64”, “prod_num”: “334”}
3. use a hash function to construct the key. e.g.: key=hashFunction(valueOf(prod_id).concat(prod_num))

Option 2 enforces using the same structure and order of key in my Product and Invoice event streams as field names are part of my keys, and as such the join condition will fail if field names do not match.

Any recommendation as to which approach would make sense is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options 1 & 2 are essentially equivalent,
with 1 being better since it retains the
two columns of your compound
[PK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key).
Any RDBMS will certainly let you model this as a **compound** PK.
The single JSON string *could* be a PK,
but it seems less convenient.
It also seems a bit fragile, as listing `prod_num`
before `prod_id` would break things.

I would only recommend option 3, hashing,
if you're willing to have such hashes
accompany all records and become the PK.
Otherwise it seems like a debugging nightmare.
"I'm looking at some *new* hash -- wonder which record
it was supposed to go with?"
Plus, due to the
[birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem),
you will need to hang on to quite a few bits of hash
to make the risk of collisions acceptably low.

Comment: thank you! I am leaning towards option 3 as it doesn't create any smart key and avoids fragility of option 2. Assuming option 3 can be enforced for usage by all the producers, do you have any recommendation on the hash function? I am thinking murmur hash which is the default hash function used by Kafka.

Comment: Murmur's advantage is that it is fast. But I doubt your system will spend an interesting fraction of CPU cycles on hashing, so murmur's speed is probably irrelevant. And an attacker (or, same thing, buggy code) can produce inputs which collide with one another. I would go with a cryptographically strong hash (essentially, a general purpose hash) such as SHA3. Typically you get more bits from it than needed. So look at your use case and its anticipated number of records, and choose an acceptably low chance of collision. Peel off appropriate size SHA3 prefix (128 bit?) and call _that_ your hash.

Comment: Thank you @J_H!

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with option 1.

```
key=valueOf(prod_id).concat(prod_num)
```

For one item, valueOf(prod_id) is 1 and prod_num is 112.

For another item, valueOf(prod_id) is 11 and prod_num is 12.

These 2 items will end up with the same key. The solution is to have some separator character that cannot be contained in the concatenated values e.g.

```
key=valueOf(prod_id).concat(":").concat(prod_num)
```